# Can I use node 'child_process' in a React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, backend, child-process

I'm building a native app with React (I plan to use it inside Electron.js later), and I need to run some local scripts and other things which are common in a native app.

This is easy with NodeJS and it's back-end abilities, but even if mine is not a web app, it seems I just can't use Node with React.

Is using 'web-like' requests and messages, even so it's a local app, the only way to do this?

Comment: I'm using similar stuff in my project (React + Electron). Check it out: https://github.com/moshfeu/y2mp3

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running in a browser, you will not be able to use `child_process` or any other node goodies like that.

Electron uses a browser, but is managed by a node process, so you will have access to all node functions: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/106/how-to-choose-read-save-delete-or-create-a-file-with-electron-framework